# apscheduler jobs in sequences waiting for ending the job bevor starting next

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a similar problem like Dinesh in this post:
[APScheduler:Trigger New job after completion of previous job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996869/apschedulertrigger-new-job-after-completion-of-previous-job/63037539#63037539)

my problem is that I'm trying to run a sequence.

after the first job "sequence 1 order 1" is finished, it is mandatory to run through "sequence 1 order 2" and then "sequence 2 order 1".

I have the correct order in the jobstore, but when I run it, everything gets mixed up. They are also executed together.

Unfortunately I'm pretty desperate, does anyone have an idea and/or an example for me?